# VBA if statement with quotient serial logic condition

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, math, logic

The following code is okey.

```
Dim myNumber As Long
If myNumber = 4 Or myNumber = 7 Or myNumber = 10 Or myNumber = 13 Or myNumber = 16 Or myNumber = 19 Or myNumber = 22 Then
    MsgBox "Hello"
End If
```

How to shorten the above code based on this serial logic?

**4**,   4+3,   **4+3+3**,   4+3+3+3,   **4+3+3+3+3**,   4+3+3+3+3+3, so on and so forth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Mod-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mod-operator) to see if your number is divisible by 3 with a rest of 0 if you subtract 4 first.

```
Sub test()
    Dim myNumber As Long
    myNumber = 4 'or however you want to fill your variable
    If (myNumber - 4) Mod 3 = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Hello"
    End If
End Sub
```

If you are expecting numbers smaller than 4 as well, you can make a small adjustment as sarh suggested:

```
Sub test()
    Dim myNumber As Long
    myNumber = 4 'or however you want to fill your variable
    If (IsMyNumber(myNumber) - 4) Mod 3 = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Hello"
    End If
End Sub

Function IsMyNumber(myNumb As Long) As Long
    IsMyNumber = IIf(myNumb < 4, 5, myNumb)
End Function
```

The function makes any number below 4 incorrect by setting it to 5 (5-4 = 1 mod 3 <> 0)

If you'd want to use it in different occasions as well, here's a more flexible function:

```
Sub test()
    Dim myNumb As Long
    myNumb = 9
    If IsMyNumber(myNumb, 4, 3) Then
        MsgBox "Hello"
    End If
End Sub

Function IsMyNumber(myNumb As Long, base As Long, addRep As Long) As Boolean
    IsMyNumber = myNumb >= base And (myNumb - base) Mod addRep = 0
End Function
```

Comment: I think it worth to check for positive number, otherwise it can match on vegative number input. I'd move it to a function returning IsMyNumber = myNumber >= 4 And myNumber Mod 3 = 1

Comment: Added your suggestion and a more flexible version in case they wanted to use it in their workbook/other occasions :)

Answer (score 1):

additional variant using `select case ...`:

```
Select Case myNumber
    Case 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Select
```